# How to reduce a matrix algebraic expression with a division?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not really sure about the algebra rules here, but it feels like my expression should be reducible.

Say I have a 1xN vector called w.

Then say I have an NxN matrix called M.

Say I have the transpose of w, t(w).

Also say I have a matrix multiplication operator X: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29

Then say I can divide a matrix (or vector) by a scalar with /

My expression is the following:

[w X M] / [w X M X t(w)]

I note that [w X M X t(w)] ends up as a scalar.

Is there a sensible way to simplify this?  What are the rules?

Comment: you just divide all entries of the vector or matrix by the scalar

Comment: yes, that requires generating the scalar in the first place.  what my question is: is this expression reducible to fewer terms?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If you have a specific vector $w$ and a specific matrix $M$, then you expression is just $\frac{1}{wMw^T}wM$ where $w^T$ is the transpose of $w$, and then you can write it out. But what kind of simplification are you looking for in general?

Comment: It just seems repetitive and like some terms should be able to drop out.

Comment: Not in general. Just look at the case when $n=2$, say $w = \begin{pmatrix}x &y\end{pmatrix}$ and $M =\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$. You end up with $wMw^T = ax^2 + bxy + cxy + dy^2$ and $wM = \begin{pmatrix}ax+cy & bx + dy\end{pmatrix}$ - there is no cancellation here that I see.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let's put this into algebraic terms.

> Say I have a 1xN vector called w.

Suppose $W $ is an $N$ dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F} $, and $w \in W$.

> Then say I have an NxN matrix called M.

Suppose $M: W \rightarrow W$ is a linear operator.

> Say I have the transpose of w, t(w).

Suppose $l_w: W \rightarrow \mathbb{F} $ is a linear functional in the dual of $W$, $W^*$, such that $<l_w, v> = \sum_{1=1}^N  w_iv_i$ for $v \in W$.

> Also say I have a matrix multiplication operator X:

Define the operation matrix composition on the space of linear operators from $W$ to $W$, $Hom(W) $

> Then say I can divide a matrix (or vector) by a scalar with /

A scalar is an element in the underlying field of the vector space, so they have inverses, so this is just extra notation for multiplication.

> My expression is the following:
>
> [w X M] / [w X M X t(w)]
>
> I note that [w X M X t(w)] ends up as a scalar.

So, this is not standard notation. Typically speaking, Linear operators act on vectors on the right, and transpose vectors (linear functionals) act on vectors in the left. However, I think what you wrote is mostly consistent if you take what you wrote and flip some things.

$$ M(w) * (l_w \circ M (w))^{-1} $$

While there's a lot that can be said about this, as far as I can tell there's no way to simplify it. The reason is because you're actually playing with a couple fundamentally different concepts here. Another way of expressing the second term is through a special kind of mapping called a bilinear form, which takes two vectors in a vector space and maps them to the field. Putting it that way, we have:

$$\frac{M(w)}{B_M(w,w)} $$

The thing about this mapping is that bilinear forms simply aren't invertible. A bilinear form on $V$ maps $V \times V $ to $\mathbb{F}$ which, even in the case of $V = \mathbb{F}$ isn't injective. There are similar mappings we could look at which might be relevant to you, like:

$$M(w) * B_M(w,w)$$

This is actually a very particular subset of multilinear maps $T: (W \times W \times W) \rightarrow W $ with a domain restricted to vectors of the form $(w,w,w)$ for $w \in W $. In this form, it may be represented as an $N \times 3N $ matrix performed on a $3N $-vector.

The reason it probably feels like it should be able to simplified is because it's so particular, but if there's any kind of greater significance to this kind of mapping, I don't know it.